# How do I freeze the active row in excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, row

Like the title says, I need to write a VBA code that copies the entire row i selected and pastes only the values so the results cannot be changed afterwards.

I have already managed to do this for the ActiveCell in the last file I worked on, but I only had to change one cell then. This is the code I used:

```
Sub Freeze()
  ActiveCell.Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

However, for this new file I have to copy the entire row and i don't want to select each individual cell. When I use this in the new file, it only works on the first cell. How can I make it work for the entire row?

Thanks.

Comment: like `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy` and `ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`??? Or like `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Value = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple code below (try to avoid Selecting cells, and active cells if possible):

```
Sub Test()

Call Freeze(3, 7)
Call Freeze(4, 8)

End Sub


Sub Freeze(rowsource As Long, rowdest As Long)

Rows(rowsource).Copy
Rows(rowdest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: true, but this way he can figure out the logic if he wants to use multiple rows, like `Rows("3:10").Copy`

Comment: true, didn't think of that. Just thought it'd be easier to implement using the numerical value.

Comment: thanks, @Shai Rado, but I need to freeze a different row each time I use the code, so this doesn't really work

Comment: @Teodoraa ok, I edited it already (you can take a look at it if you want)

Answer (score 0):

> Paste:=xlPasteValues

You do not need to copy paste values unless you are trying to copy formats as well.

Try this. Replace the sheet names with the relevant sheet names. Also Replace X,Y with the relevant row numbers. If you are using multiple rows then change `Rows(X)` to `Range("X:X")` and similarly `Range("Y:Y")`

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(X).Value =  _
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Y).Value
```

Comment: I do need to keep the formats actually. Plus I need to work with whichever row I select (it changes daily), so I can't use a pre-set row number. Your solution is good, just not really what i need :)

Comment: `it changes daily`So use a variable :)